# In mysql(innodb),how does the big table affect buffer(memory)?

Tags: mysql, database, caching, innodb

I know if a table is too big, the indexes can hardly be fit into the buffer_pool,
    so using index may result in a large number of random disk IO. So the full table scan,
    in general, is probably much faster than index scan even though it only reads about %1 rows.

```
What I am confused about is : 
    [0] If there are a big table( 30 millions rows),and many small tables(each table can be fit into memory(buffer)),
        will the big table also affect query about small tables ?
        My logic is <======>
            the buffer is shared by the whole database, so the big table will take most of buffer. 
            So the indexes of small tables can also hardly be fit into buffer(or it's often
            removed from the buffer). Then the above conclusion(full table scan vs index scan) can be applied to this case .
    [1] When the big table are partitioned into may small tables(in just one machine), the situation of buffer should keep identical.
           So such partition cannot solve this problem(full table scan vs index  scan), right? so the "big table" should not mean "one big table", but the "huge database or the sum of data is large"
```

To sum up, is my inclusion right? if wrong, why? Please give me a hint. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buffer_pool` is shared across all tables, data and index.  But the rest of what you said is needs to focus on "blocks" instead of "tables".

Caching is performed on a **block** basis.  A block (in InnoDB) is 16KB.  Most of the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is dedicated to data and index blocks.

The cache is run (approximately) as **LRU** (Least Recently Used) -- That is, the least recently used blocks are tossed from the cache when other blocks are needed.

No, a table or index is not "entirely" loaded into the cache.  Instead, the desired blocks are loaded (and purged) when needed.

If all the data *and* indexes fit into the cache, then (eventually) all the blocks will 'live' there.

If the data plus indexes are too big, then blocks will come and go as needed.  *Usually* this is nearly as good as having them all loaded.  For example, if you are usually using "recent" records, then the blocks containing them will 'stay' in the cache; meanwhile "old" blocks will get bumped out.

If you are using **UUIDs** (GUIDs), performance can get really bad -- this is because of the random nature of such indexed values.

**Full table scans** (and full index scans) should be avoided whether or not things are too big to fit in cache.  They are costly, and they can *usually* be avoided by proper indexing and/or query formulation.

When you do a full table scan on a table that is bigger than the cache, something's gotta give.  You will have to do some I/O, and some blocks will be bumped out of cache.  However, there is a technique built in that prevents blindly purging the entire cache for an occasional table scan.  For further discussion, research `innodb_old_blocks_pct`.  (No, I don't recommend changing it from the default 37%.)

What do you mean by **partitioning a table**?  If you mean the builtin `PARTITION` mechanism, then so what?  If you scan a *table* you are scanning *all* the partitions.  Same number blocks; same impact on the cache.

I have dealt with sets of tables that exceed the buffer_pool by a factor of 10 or more.  I can discuss performance techniques, but I need a specific `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (with or without `PARTITIONs`) and some of the naughty queries (such as table scans).

The **Optimizer chooses** between doing a table scan and using an index based on a variety of statistics, etc.  A Rule of Thumb is that, if more than 20% of the rows need to be touched, it will do a table scan instead of bouncing between the index and the data.  (Note: the cutoff is much higher than the 1% you mentioned.)

An Index is structured as a `BTree` in 16KB blocks, so it is very efficient to start in the middle and scan a range.  For example:  `INDEX(last_name)` for `WHERE last_name LIKE 'J%'` would probably do a "range scan" of 10% of the index, even if that involved bouncing over to the table a lot.

Comment: thanks for your answer，I undersand what you mentioned but I still have little confusions： if the blocks of the whole database are bigger,then the probability of having to do disk IO when accessing  a table(even if it is small) may be higher,right?because it's blocks may be already removed from the cache.                                  So when optimizer chooses the index scan(except index converting),the times of random disk may increase, right?maybe the threshold of selecting full table scan or index scan should be adjusted according to the number of blocks of whole database，right？

Comment: @pyb1993 - The _cost_ (time) of one disk hit is essentially constant.  The _number_ of disk hits is what I am discussing.  Your generalities fall apart because the _order_ of records in the index and in the data versus the _order_ that they need to be accessed -- these can lead to very little I/O versus a lot of I/O versus something in between.